# iOS app crash when accessing iPhone photo library even with key NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription defined

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have an application that I am updating to Xcode 8.2.1. Previously the access to the Camera and the Photo Library was working correctly. But now the app crashes with the following message :

```
This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.
The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Many posts on stackoverflow just says "add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key" to your `info.plist`.

**But i have done such a thing !**
And my app still crashes !

My `info.plist` file :

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permet à l'application de connaitre l&apos;emplacement de vos posts</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses camera</string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
```

The code is mainly based on a Apple example ...

```
- (IBAction)showImagePickerForPhotoPicker:(id)sender
{
    [self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    // ...
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
    // ..
    }

    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Well, I am really stuck ... Maybe it's a project configuration problem ?

Comment: try cleaning your project, if still not work delete the app and reinstall it.

Comment: Even if this two doesn't work go to settings and reset privacy setting of your device.

Comment: cleaning the project, and delete the app and reinstall it. does not works ...How do you reset privacy settings ?

Comment: U can try remove $(PRODUCT_NAME) and try again.

Comment: I don't have it initially but many samples uses this code so i modify info.plist this way .... I can roll back ...

Comment: I replace the content of the key with "App uses photos" and it still crashes ...

Comment: SETTINGS > GENERAL > RESET > Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: Well I have found the problem : When migrating the app i made a copy and i made a big mess with info.plist files it seems that a other file with a weird name was used by Xcode ! Cleaning up all that mess make my app works again, anyway Thanks for your help !!! It help me to think again as far as obvious solution where not working, I should consider I was 'the problem' so I investigate new solutions. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try to remove Permet from this line ----<string>Permet à l'application de connaitre l&apos;emplacement de vos posts</string> and them test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologies but it was my fault, when migrating I med some mess with info.plist files.

Comment: Well, for me, I added NSCameraUsageDescription to the unit test and not the main program. All roads lead to iOS app crash I guess.